# I can't get the REPL plugin to work for some languages

Tags: windows-8, sublime-text-2

I've installed the SublimeREPL plugin, but when I try to use REPL for some languages it gives me this error:

> Windows Error(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

This happens for some languages but not all. Python and Scala, for example, run fine, but PHP doesn't. I have PHP installed correctly and I've added it to the path. I haven't configured REPL in any way though. Should I, or is it something else that I should do to get it to work?

I'm using Windows 8 and my PHP version is not compiled with the readline option. Could that be a problem?